# How do I assign output from a loop as a variable

Tags: python, loops

I currently have this list: `['/', 'home', 'documents', 'pictures']`

and I have this loop:

```py
for i, dir in enumerate(path):
    if i == 0:
        print(dir, end="")
    elif i == len(path) - 1:
        print(dir)
    else:
        print(dir, end='/')
```

which will output `/home/documents/pictures`.

How can I assign the output of this loop to a variable?

e.g.
`print(var)` will output `/home/documents/pictures`

Comment: You can't. You have to build a string, e.g. using something like `io.StringIO` or by appending to a string instead of `print`ing. `str.join` could work, but will involve some extra shenanigans to handle the leading `/`

Comment: You can join (https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/join) the list, even without the loop

Comment: Why the loop? `'/'.join(path)` (will create a double-leading `/` though) or even better `os.path.join(*path)`

Answer (score 1):

You should assign to variable

```
path = ['/', 'home', 'documents', 'pictures']

var = ""

for i, dir in enumerate(path):
    if i == 0:
        var += dir
    elif i == len(path) - 1:
        var += dir
    else:
        var += dir + '/'

print( var )
```

But it is much simpler with `os.path`

```
import os

path = ['/', 'home', 'documents', 'pictures']

var = os.path.join(*path)

print( var )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want combine each value of in the list to a string variable. Here is my solution
hopes helps you!

```py
dir=['/', 'home', 'documents', 'pictures']
path=''
for i in dir: #read the array
    if(i!='/'):
        path+='/'
        path+=i #append the new value in the String variable
print(path)
```

Comment: Concatenating a string in a loop is very inefficient as memory needs to be allocated, copied and reallocated constantly

Comment: Also `else: continue` is not needed at all.